# gnu parallel: Warning: This job was killed because it timed out

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

I am running multiple commands on remote hosts. if I pass my command directly in my ssh script it's working, once I pass it from another script as an argument it gives me a result of my first host and times out on the rest as soon as it loges into them. How can I pass a command from another script and get this working, or what is the reason that my ssh script executes commands on one host only?

```
#Linux ssh
My_ssh_function () {
    sudo sshpass -p "$1" ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  root@"$2" "$command_linux"
}
export -f My_ssh_function 
export -p command_linux
export -p file_with_targets_linux
export -p passwords
parallel -j 2 --tag My_ssh_function :::: "$passwords" "$file_with_targets_linux"
```

command that I am passing from a different file:
(working fine as long as I don't send it form another script to my script above)

```
 ""/sbin/dmidecode | /usr/bin/grep "Product Name:" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4, $5}' > /tmp/result && free -h --si |grep Mem | awk '{print $2}' >> /tmp/result && dmidecode -s system-serial-number >> /tmp/result && hostname |awk -F"." '{print $1}' >> /tmp/result && cat /tmp/result |xargs""
```

> ```
> parallel: Warning: My_ssh_function host_password_string 135.121.157.80
> parallel: Warning: This job was killed because it timed out:
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaving out something from your example: The example is not complete, because GNU Parallel will never give that error if you do not have a `--timeout`.

That said you should test that `My_ssh_function` works as expected.

So try this:

```
# remove --tag from parallel
parallel --dryrun ... > myfile.sh
# Does myfile.sh contain what you expect now?
cat myfile.sh
# Does it run as you expect?
bash myfile.sh
```

If it works for some of the hosts, I guess the `sshpass ... ssh` fails for some hosts.

If it does not work for any host, I guess that your quoting is off.

Personally I would:

- Remove `sudo`: It is unclear why you need to run `sshpass` as root.
- Not use `sshpass`. Instead use `ssh-copy-id` once to make it possible for your user to log in. Use `ssh-agent` to still have a passphrase on your ssh key, but not having to enter it when logging in. That way a criminal who gets access to a backup of `~/.ssh` will not be able to use your key.
- When that is setup you should be able to let GNU Parallel do the logging in directly using `--ssh` and `--slf` and use `--onall` or `--nonall` to run the command.
- When that works you might consider converting your long one-line script to a bash function and use `env_parallel` to copy it to the remote machine.

Something like this:

```
at_startup() {
    # Add sshkey to sshagent unless already done
    if [ -e ~/.ssh/SSH_AUTH_SOCK ] ; then
        export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`cat ~/.ssh/SSH_AUTH_SOCK`
    fi
    if [ -e ~/.ssh/SSH_AGENT_PID ] ; then
        export SSH_AGENT_PID=`cat ~/.ssh/SSH_AGENT_PID`
    fi
    if ssh-add -l ; then
        true
    else
        eval `ssh-agent` ssh-add ~/.ssh/id*[^b] &&
            echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > ~/.ssh/SSH_AUTH_SOCK &&
            echo $SSH_AGENT_PID > ~/.ssh/SSH_AGENT_PID
    fi
}

setup_ssh_keys_once() {
  setupone() {
    sshpass -p "$1" ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  root@"$2"
  }
  export -f setupone
  parallel setupone :::: "$passwords" "$file_with_targets_linux" 
}

env_parallel --session

command_linux() {
  /sbin/dmidecode | /usr/bin/grep "Product Name:" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4, $5}' > /tmp/result &&
    free -h --si |grep Mem | awk '{print $2}' >> /tmp/result &&
    dmidecode -s system-serial-number >> /tmp/result &&
    hostname | awk -F"." '{print $1}' >> /tmp/result &&
    cat /tmp/result |xargs
}

# Yes: env_parallel can copy a function to a remote server - even if it is not exported
env_parallel --ssh 'ssh -l root' --slf "$file_with_targets_linux" --nonall command_linux
```

Comment: Thanks Ole! 
env_parallel is a great idea! I will look into that, as for the answer to this problem, the quotation was off.